# Prevent React component from rendering before props ready

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm a React noobie, or midbie. This component is mappping an empty `posts` array coming as a prop from its parent.

How do I make it wait until the props having finished updating before doing the `return()` where the mapping happens?

I think I need to use `useEffect` but I'm not sure the syntax.

```
const Timeline = props => {
  console.log(props.posts.length); // logs twice: initially 0, then 6 a microsecond later.

  useEffefct(()=>{
    // if props is all done and ready, goto return statement
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <>
      <CreatePost />
      <div className="post-list">
        {props.posts.map((post, i) => ( // this maps the initial empty array
          <Post key={i} post={post} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Timeline;
```

Comment: By definition, having props means the component is ready. Instead, don't have the parent _create_ the `Timeline` until its props are the ones you need used, so don't blindly build a `<Timeline {...props} />`, actually make sure you only build it when the property values make sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use an inline condition to prevent mapping if array is not filled yet.

```
{(props.posts.length > 0) && props.posts.map((post, i) => (
   <Post key={i} post={post} />
))}
```